# Route to different services based on URL template

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, odata

I'm working on Backward Compatible project. In which, a **WCF** service supports OData v1-v3. I'm building **ASP .NET Web API** which support OData v4.

I have to call them as shows here:
http://localhost:17505/api/v4/Products should call **ASP .NET Web API** service.
http://localhost:17505/api/v3/Products should call **WCF** service

Where should the routing take place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found and implemented the answer finally. It seems `http.sys` handles everything we need. Only the routing template should differ.

Had `initiateApis` method which calls `Start` methods of both WebAPI and WCF classes with parameter as the uri.

In WebAPI class - `WebApi.cs`

```
WebApp.Start<WebApi>(uri);
```

In WCF class - `WcfService.cs`

```
_serviceHost = new DataServiceHost(typeof(WcfService), new Uri[0]);
_serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IRequestHandler), httpBinding, uri);
```

So whenever passing the url,

```
WebApi.Start("http://localhost:17505/api/v4/");
WcfService.Start("http://localhost:17505/api/v3/");
```

Happy Coding :)